# How load,insert,update asp.net C# using handsontable

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, handsontable

I am very new to Handsontable and looking for load,Insert,Update, asp.net C#,mssql  Can anyone please help me with code snippet.For insert,update and load

Comment: It works with ajax. there are examples in jsfiddle of how to load it http://handsontable.com/examples.html#fndtn-basic give it a try if you are stuck let us know

Comment: @Zaki I need with asp.net C# with using Handsontable

Comment: As I said set up your project try to go through the samples and if it doesnt work post here and will help you :)